# How can I combine properties of rotational data?

Tags: algorithm, math, rotation

I have a project I'm working on that requires rotational data (yaw, pitch, roll) to be taken from a few different sensors to be combined in code.

- The first sensor I have, I can get good angels from, but has a very bad drifting problem.
- The second sensor can has very good angles with minimum drifting, but only has a -90 to 90 degree range
  of motion.

My question is how can I combine these two sensors data so that I have minimum drifting and a 360° range?
I can provide sample data if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a good model for the drift? Do you know if it is linear, or Brownian, or whatever?

Comment: Very interesting question, however, it's off topic in this forum. Try dsp.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @Beta It seems to be very linear, I know this could mean I am adding values, but I have looked through my code for 5 hours at this point, and I don't think I have added anything.

Comment: That means that if you can bring the second sensor to bear at two different times, you can measure the drift and correct for it at all times.